# trying an example from rise4fun / z3 / tutorial / strategies

Tags: z3, smt, sat

some example from the rise4fun-site:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const y Int)
(declare-const z Int)
(declare-const a Int)        ;  this is added

(assert (= a 3 ))            ; this is added:  a := 3
(assert (< 0 x  10))         ; rewritten, but same constraint
(assert (< 0 y  10))
(assert (< 0 z  10))

(assert (= (+ (* 3 y) (* 2 x)) z))        ; plain function from rise4fun
;(assert (= (+ (* a y) (* 2 x)) z))       ; here literal 3 is replaced by a

(check-sat-using (then (using-params simplify :arith-lhs true :som true)
                       normalize-bounds
                       lia2pb
                       pb2bv
                       bit-blast
                       sat))
(get-model)
(get-info :version)
```

when i comment the plain function from rise4fun and uncomment my function, the solver will fail to produce a result and respond with 'unknown'  (tried with 4.8.0). Isn't the solver or some preprocessor smart enough to see that 'a' is just a constant with fixed value 3?

Answer (score 1):

That's right, the `simplify` tactic is not smart enough to propagate values because it would be too expensive in general. However, `ctx-simplify` or `propagate-values` do the job. For instance:

```
(check-sat-using (then (using-params simplify :arith-lhs true :som true)
                       propagate-values
                       normalize-bounds
                       lia2pb
                       pb2bv
                       bit-blast
                       sat))
```

Comment: hmm - if constant-propagation is too hard word for simplify, what then does it simplfy? BTW, who would be resonsible to convert existing boolean formulas to CNF, as required by the sat-solver ?
Anyway, i propose to extend the documentation sample in rise4fun by the propagate-values parameter

Comment: `simplify` performs theory-specific, local simplification and (some) normalization; see here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/ast/rewriter/th_rewriter.cpp